# Maven : cannot find symbol : class ClassName location: package com.packagename

Tags: java, maven

When doing a "mvn clean install" on a maven project, on which I don't have any dependencies problem, Some classes on sub-packages doesn't recognize other classes on upper packages (on the same project),

An illustration of the situation is on the image:

[image]

So, ContractOperation.java can't import ContractData.java.

The error is :
src/main/java/com/mycompany/product/ws/server/ops/ContractOperation.java:[69,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ContractData
location: package com.mycompany.product.ws.helpers

Any idea please.
Thanks in advise.

Comment: may be obvious but does the classes have the correct `package` and `import` declarations? can you post the "head" (initial part) of the files?

Comment: Thank you Marco for your reply. I have found that the classes doensn't even exist. I have been given the svn url and imported the project. So I assumed that they exist, which is not the case. So I have to delete the question and thank you for your reply